# Powershell-string to listview

Tags: c#, powershell

I have created a C# application that, among other things, should get the installed programs on a remote computer by using powershell code. I can run the code but it only adds the items to a single column in a single row and I'm not able to scroll in it.

Can you tell me how to add each program to a new row, where the headers are: Program, Vendor, Version ?
Here is the ps1 code:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock {
    $SWInstalled = get-wmiobject Win32_product | select @{Label="Program";Expression={$_.Name}}, version, vendor | Sort-Object Program
    $SWInstalled | ft
}
```

Here is the relevant c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.IO;

namespace ClientCheck
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string RunScript(string scriptText)
        {
            // create Powershell runspace 
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

            // open it 
            runspace.Open();
            runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("ComputerName", CompnameInput.Text);
            runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("user", UserNameInput.Text);

            // create a pipeline and feed it the script text 
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

            // add an extra command to transform the script output objects into nicely formatted strings 
            // remove this line to get the actual objects that the script returns. For example, the script 
            // "Get-Process" returns a collection of System.Diagnostics.Process instances. 
            pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

            // execute the script 
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

            // close the runspace 
            runspace.Close();

            // convert the script result into a single string 
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }

            // return the results of the script that has 
            // now been converted to text 
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
        // helper method that takes your script path, loads up the script 
        // into a variable, and passes the variable to the RunScript method 
        // that will then execute the contents 
        private string LoadScript(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from our file. 
                // The using statement also closes the StreamReader. 
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
                {

                    // use a string builder to get all our lines from the file 
                    StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder();

                    // string to hold the current line 
                    string curLine;

                    // loop through our file and read each line into our 
                    // stringbuilder as we go along 
                    while ((curLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // read each line and MAKE SURE YOU ADD BACK THE 
                        // LINEFEED THAT IT THE ReadLine() METHOD STRIPS OFF 
                        fileContents.Append(curLine + "\n");
                    }

                    // call RunScript and pass in our file contents 
                    // converted to a string 
                    return fileContents.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Let the user know what went wrong. 
                string errorText = "The file could not be read:";
                errorText += e.Message + "\n";
                return errorText;
            }


        private void GetSWButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SWList.Items.Clear();
            SWList.Items.Add((RunScript(LoadScript(@"C:\Get_Installed_Software.ps1"))));
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is the XAML code:

```
<ListView x:Name="SWList" Height="404" Margin="36,169,36,51" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderThickness="0" Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="2">
    <ListView.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform AngleX="-0.0"/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform X="0.346"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </ListView.RenderTransform>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Program" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Program'}" Width="440"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Vendor" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding 'Vendor'}" Width="281"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Version" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Version'}" Width="150"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Not sure if it will solve the problem for you but if your going to have another piece of code pick up the results of the function you should skip piping the results to ft, that cmdlet will change your nice object into an array that is designed for easy viewing in the console but that other code will have trouble dealing with

Comment: @MikeGaruccio Oh, I just added that for testing.
If i remove it, I also have to remove the DisplaymemberBinding from the xaml, otherwise it cant add it to the table. And when I remove that I get the same output in all columns, still all in one row. Every software gets 5 rows: Name, Vendor, Version, PSComputername and RunspaceID. And then the list contiues like that in a single row.. Hope you understand, I can upload a printscreen somewhere if you like.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looping through the PSObject results and appending them to a single StringBuilder. When you're adding the results from RunScript to the SWList items, you're only adding that single string. That's why it's only showing up in one row.

And as Mike indicated in his comment, by using the Format-Table cmdlet at the end of your script you are undoing the nice object properties generated by PowerShell; this is almost certainly what is causing it to show up in a single column.

Here's an example of an updated RunScript method that returns a collection of objects instead of a single string. Note how I changed the method signature to return a Collection of PSObjects instead of just a string. I also commented out the line that adds Out-String to the end of the pipeline. This means that you'll get the raw PSObjects returned from this function. Depending on what script you run, the BaseObject of these PSObjects will be of a different type. You can access the BaseObject property of these PSObjects to get the values you need.

```
private Collection<PSObject> RunScript(string scriptText)
    {
        // create Powershell runspace 
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

        // open it 
        runspace.Open();
        runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("ComputerName", CompnameInput.Text);
        runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("user", UserNameInput.Text);

        // create a pipeline and feed it the script text 
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

        // add an extra command to transform the script output objects into nicely formatted strings 
        // remove this line to get the actual objects that the script returns. For example, the script 
        // "Get-Process" returns a collection of System.Diagnostics.Process instances. 
      //  pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

        // execute the script 
        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

        // close the runspace 
        runspace.Close();

        return results;
```

}

Comment: Oh, I just added that for testing.
If i remove it, I also have to remove the DisplaymemberBinding from the xaml, otherwise it cant add it to the table. And when I remove that I get the same output in all columns, still all in one row. Every software gets 5 rows: Name, Vendor, Version, PSComputername and RunspaceID. And then the list contiues like that in a single row.. Hope you understand, I can upload a printscreen somewhere if you like.

Comment: I still think " stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());" is your main issue.

Comment: Yes, I guess so.. I'm no C#-pro, do you know any way to make it work like I want?

Comment: I don't think the stringbuilder is the problem, from what I'm seeing that's basically just loading the script file into memory for C# to run, which I'm not sure you need but shouldn't cause a problem, at least not with the results formatting.  I think I may have found the issue tho, your adding an Out-String to the pipeline, that's going to take your objects and turn them into a string, does commenting that out help anything?  Also if your not 100% comfortable in C# it may be easier to write the whole thing in powershell? learn-powershell.net has a great tutorial on how to do that with a GUI

Comment: @MikeGaruccio I just tried commenting that out and it does not work either..

Actually, I already created some powershell-GUI-applications but I want to do this in C#, I want to learn that as well!

Comment: What if you just return "results" from RunScript instead of collecting those up in a stringbuilder?

Comment: @jbsmith As I said, I'm just getting started with c# and I'm kind of dumb when it comes to this.. Can you guide me on where and what to change more exacty?